# How do I fix a directory error on Openssl

Tags: openssl

When I type in a code I keep getting an error message and I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
Can't open textFile.txt for reading, No such file or directory
25769902144:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('textFile.txt','rb')
25769902144:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
error in aes-256-ecb
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the cause of the error is that `textFile.txt` doesn't exists.

I just had a similar error when using `openssl ca`, so I'm going to assume that's also the command you used. If that is the case, check your OpenSSL CA config file to see what kind of file `textFile.txt` is supposed to be and create it with appropriate content.

For example the errors I encountered were about about missing `index.txt` and `serial.txt` files, with a config similar to this:

```
[ CA_default ]
database = index.txt
serial   = serial.txt
```

Simply creating an empty `index.txt` file and a `serial.txt` file with a generated serial fixed the issue. Maybe `textFile.txt` is also a serial file but that's impossible to tell without seeing your config.